# adb completely freezes system

Tags: 18.04, android, freeze, android-sdk, adb

Whenever I utilize *any* (except for `--version`) adb command (`adb devices`, for instance), my system completely freezes and I have to reboot. My laptop is a Lenovo B50-30 running a (relatively) fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation, no phones are connected. What do I have to do in order to get adb working ?

What I have already tried :

- Connecting phone
- Changing BIOS settings - disabled legacy USB & changed legacy to UEFI boot
- Running adb using `sudo`
- Removing `tlp` (`sudo apt remove tlp`)
- Checking whether port is in use (`sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 5037`)
- Upgrading adb (`sudo apt upgrade adb`)
- Running different adb commands

**Update** : I have tried a different computer with (relatively similar) specs but an older Ubuntu (16.04) and also an older kernel, and it worked pretty much seamlessly.

Related :

- [ubuntu freezes initializing ADB when running android studio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738064/ubuntu-freezes-initializing-adb-when-running-android-studio)
- [Linux system freezes when adb start-server is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29172905/linux-system-freezes-when-adb-start-server-is-called)
- [Problems with ADB (locks up after starting Daemon)](https://forums.androidcentral.com/software-development-hacking/49503-problems-adb-locks-up-after-starting-daemon.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old question but I was stuck with this problem too. So I found what's causing it: the BIOS.

There should be a option to enable/disabe **xHCI Support** - enable /disable external USB3.0 Controller.

If it's disabled, adb won't freeze the OS

Comment: I unfortunately can't test this anymore as my old device died, and it is working flawlessly on my new one